# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, string, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use a method to process a `String`... But I'm getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String kuros.com.ipsiscontroller.stringFilter.setStringParam(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at kuros.com.ipsiscontroller.AddActivity.getParameters(AddActivity.java:147)
```

stringFilter.class

```
String setStringParam(String parameter){
        /*String finalParam = "";
        String fillString = "";

            if (parameter.length() < LENGTH_PARAMETERS) {
                int missingChars = LENGTH_PARAMETERS - parameter.length();
                Log.d("STRING_TAG missingChars", String.valueOf(missingChars));
                for (int i = 0; i < missingChars; i++) {
                    //fillString = fillString + "x";
                    fillString += "x";
                }
            }
            finalParam = parameter + fillString;
            Log.d("STRING_TAG", finalParam);*/

        return parameter;
    }
```

As you can see I commented most on the method just to see I get the same `String` back... but is not working either.
This is line 147.

```
String test = sf.setStringParam("a");
```

Comment: Are you sure `sf` is not null?

Comment: What is sf? it seems to be null

Comment: What **is** `sf`? I don't even see it.

Comment: Make sure that you have created object for sf

Comment: `sf` where is it ? seems `invisible`

Comment: put your complete code here please

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That method is not static so you will need an instance of `stringFilter` to invoke that method.

You are calling an instance method on a null instance of `stringFilter`